# Profile2 Images

Tags: media, users

I have a image field in profile2, the images that are added to the profile are uploaded to /sites/default/files

This will be a mess with a lot of profiles and 5 images per profile. Also when the images are deleted from the profile they still remain in the folder.

Is there a way have each user's profile2 images goto their own location or at least one folder with all the pictures?

Also I would to know if there is a way so when the picture is removed from the profile or the account is deleted all the pictures are deleted to?

I am using the latest version of Drupal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help  you.

In Drupal 7 you can use [**TOKEN**](https://drupal.org/project/token) module.

- Download and install **Token module**.
- By considering that you have add the new image field using the path `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`
- Go to your image field settings(admin/config/people/accounts/fields)
  and edit the image field

  [image]
- Click ***Browse available tokens*** link to show the available tokens

  [image]
- In my case I'm saving my **FILE DIRECTORY** path name as `profile-pictures/user-[current-user:uid]-[current-user:name]`

  [image]
- When ever you upload files it will be stored in the **profile-pictures/user-UID-USERNAME**
- You can customize the **FILE DIRECTORY** path as per your requirement.
- You can use [**file_delete**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_delete/7) and [**file_usage_delete**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_usage_delete/7) to delete the file once removed.
- To delete the folder you can use USER API **[hook_user_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_delete/7)**

NOTE:

- You can also refer [**IMCE**](https://drupal.org/project/imce) module.